# Multivariate Regression (Error on the Gradient Descent)

Tags: python, machine-learning, integer, regression, gradient-descent

```
X = df.drop(columns="Math") 
y = df.iloc[:, 4] 
theta = np.array([0]*len(X.columns))

def hypothesis(theta, X):
    return theta*X

def computeCost(X, y, theta):
    y1 = hypothesis(theta, X)
    y1=np.sum(y1, axis=1)
    return sum(np.sqrt((y1-y)**2))/(2*47)

def gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, i):
    J = []  #cost function in each iterations
    k = 0
    while k < i:        
        y1 = hypothesis(theta, X)
        y1 = np.sum(y1, axis=1)
        for c in range(0, len(X.columns)):
            theta[c] = theta[c] - alpha*(sum((y1-y)*X.iloc[:,c])/len(X))
        j = computeCost(X, y, theta)
        J.append(j)
        k += 1
    return J, j, theta

J, j, theta = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, 0.05, 10000)
```

The dataset is consists of five columns. The first is the column of ones for the bias term. The second until the last are int64 consisting numerical value from 1-100. The second field represents the Physics scores, the third represents the Science scores, the fourth represents the Statistics scores, while the last one represents the Math scores. I am trying to use the 1st until the 4th column to predict the 5th column (Math)

The error will appear as follows:

```
    OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-d17a8fb83984> in <module>()
----> 1 J, j, theta = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, 0.05, 10000)

<ipython-input-25-bfec0d0edcfa> in gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, i)
      6         y1 = np.sum(y1, axis=1)
      7         for c in range(0, len(X.columns)):
----> 8             theta[c] = theta[c] - alpha*(sum((y1-y)*X.iloc[:,c])/len(X))
      9         j = computeCost(X, y, theta)
     10         J.append(j)

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C
```

Answer (score 0):

You ran into the error most likely due to a combination of:

1. Setting `theta` to be integer with `theta = np.array([0]*len(X.columns))`. You can do something like `np.zeros(np.shape(X)[1])`
2. Setting a learning rate that is too high, you can check your cost or `J`, it might be increasing indicating the learning rate is too high
3. Not very sure about your bias terms as 1, this might depend on your range of values.

So if I test your code with a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(111)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(50,4)),
                 columns=['const','Physics','Science','Stats'])

df['const'] = 1
df['Math'] = 0.2*df['Physics'] + 0.4*df['Science'] + 0.5*df['Stats']
```

Then initialize:

```
X = df.drop(columns="Math") 
y = df.iloc[:, 4] 

theta = np.ones(X.shape[1])
```

Then run with a smaller learning rate:

```
J, j, theta = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, 0.0001,100)

theta

array([0.98851902, 0.1950524 , 0.39639991, 0.49143374])
```